# Kivy - TextInput behavior similar to Excel

Tags: python, kivy

I'm editing a text of TextInput 'A' in Kivy application. I now need to copy text of TextInput 'B' to the A, by clicking on B, without A loosing it's focus.

Something like when I write an equation in Excel, I can click on another cell and the cell ID is copied to the equation, instead of selecting the another cell.

How would I do this, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if that is what you are looking for. If you click into the second `TextInput` it will copy the content of the first `TextInput`. I am using a `main.py`

```
# main.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class AnswerApp(App):

    text_of_text_input_1 = StringProperty()

    def change_text_of_text_input_2(self):
        self.text_of_text_input_1 = self.root.ids.text_input_1.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AnswerApp().run()
```

and the kv file `answer.kv`.

```
# answer.kv
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    TextInput:
        id: text_input_1
        text: "text_input_1"
    TextInput:
        text: app.text_of_text_input_1
        on_focus: app.change_text_of_text_input_2()
```

Comment: I want the different way - to copy textbox I click (can be multiple ones), to the textbox I'm currenty editing.